# Why doesn't LIMIT work in Stack Exchange Data Explorer?

Tags: support, data-explorer, sql

For some reason this isn't working in Data Explorer:

```
select ownerUserId, creationDate from posts LIMIT 1
```

I'm getting

> Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '1'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Data Explorer is using T-SQL, Microsoft's SQL dialect for SQL Server. It does not have the `LIMIT` command, instead, you have to use `TOP`:

```
select TOP 1 ownerUserId, creationDate from posts
```

Comment: ah I see thanks for clarifying, I come from a psql background. Any advice on a replacement for `distinct on` for t-sql?

Comment: @abbood https://stackoverflow.com/q/5808854/4751173